# Vue / JavaScript - How to push dynamic object to array

Tags: javascript

I have this data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6937729",
        "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=116db0312&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
        "availability": true,
        "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
        "descriptionDDDD": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano sunt alegerea perfecta pentru a evita aparitia calcaielor crapate sau a deshidratarii pielii picioarelor! Botosii SPA sunt creati din material textil, flausat. Fiind flausati, mentin o temperatura constanta a parafinei atunci cand sunt utilizati. Folosind Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano vei obtine intretinerea picioarelor, dar vei avea parte si de momente de relaxare! ATENTIE! Acesti botosi nu au parafina inclusa, aceasta se cumpara separat!",
        "id": "6937729",
        "image_link": [
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/6/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633286.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633285.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/7/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633287.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/8/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7633288.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/5/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano~7643575.jpg"
        ],
        "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/parafina-cosmetica-2/botosi-tratament-parafina-soft-ingrid-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
        "price": "19.9",
        "product type": "Epilare",
        "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
        "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
        "title": "Botosi Tratament Parafina Soft Ingrid SensoPRO Milano",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
        "date_upd": 1665255561
    },
    {
        "_id": "6937887",
        "affiliate_url": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=5cd952501&aff_code=4b8685e94&campaign_unique=4b9a6d5ea",
        "availability": true,
        "brand": "SensoPRO Milano",
        "descriptionDDDD": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano, accesorii pentru unghii, se adreseaza in mod special ojelor permanente Magnetto pentru Cat Eye Effect, in realizarea efectului special de \"Cat Eyes\".",
        "id": "6937887",
        "image_link": [
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/4/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618904.jpg",
            "https://cdnmpro.com/677236441/p/raw/3/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano~7618903.jpg"
        ],
        "link": "https://www.kitunghii.ro/accesorii-manichiura/magnet-cat-eye-dublu-pentru-oja-sensopro-milano?utm_source=portal&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=2parale",
        "price": "9.9",
        "product type": "Accesorii Unghii",
        "test_value_name1": "test_content_value1",
        "test_value_name2": "test_content_value2",
        "title": "Magnet Cat Eye Dublu pentru Oja SensoPRO Milano",
        "updated_at": "2022-08-31T12:29:56.000000Z",
        "date_upd": 1665248423
    },
]
```

My Goal is to build a table using that data where the table **header** will be the object **key** and value will be that corresponding object keys **value**.

## **What I am doing **

First I get the key from the first object and store it to `productKeys` :

```
//Get the keys of products 
Object.keys(response.data.data[0]).forEach(key => {
    this.productKeys.push(key)
})
```

Now, I am adding that keys to `columns`:

```
// Set table the header
this.productKeys.forEach( (key ) => {
    this.columns.push({
        label : this.capitalizeFirstLetter(key.replace(/_/g, ' ')),
        field : key, 
        tdClass : 'collapseCol'
    })
});
```

Now, I can see the table header. Its time to set the corresponding header value. To do that, I am doing:

```
response.data.data.forEach( ( item ) => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        this.productKeys.forEach(()=>{
            this.rows.push({
                [key] : item[key]
            });    
        });
    });
});
```

**BUT,** It doesn't set the table cell value to that corresponding header. Currenlty the output is something like this: https://prnt.sc/Z3QHK5ZI6-Ib

Its should be fill up all the rows. **I think the issue is at this line**

```
this.productKeys.forEach((key2)=>{
    this.rows.push({
        [key] : item[key]
    });    
});
```

Can you tell me how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running 3 loop is not required, you already have a key array. just use that

```
response.data.data.forEach( ( item ) => {
        let temp_row = {}
        this.productKeys.forEach((key)=>{
            temp_row ={...temp_row,
                [key] : item[key]
            };    
        });
        this.rows.push(temp_row)
});
```

Although I would suggest to handle some of the calculations in backend API, such that you at least get the `key` array from backend to be more efficient.

Comment: I think you could also simplify the logic using `Array.map` to assign some of the arrays.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://codeshare.io/ZJdJMo, if so then I don't get any data.

Comment: hope the code snippets are in order in your vue component. Please `console.log(this.productKeys)` before you start your loop and check if it has all the keys

Comment: Yes, I have the keys as array: https://prnt.sc/-iR3UsmzHJZ-

Comment: Okay. this code is showing data but all are duplicate: https://codeshare.io/QnXnMR

Comment: I have updated, please check

Comment: Yes, its seems working, let me check again.

Comment: WOW, It's Great. Working fine, Thank a lot my friend :)

Comment: I would suggest you to handle some of the tasks on backend side.

Comment: like? Can you tell me a bit more ?

Comment: you can have the keys array sent from backend, as `columnHeaders`, if you know on backend side that this api is for table then you should leverage the backend to ease some load on the ui

Comment: Ah...I see. Thanks for that suggetions